# AWK format data based on columns with multiple rows

Tags: awk, rows

See below I have this data which I want to format so that I can insert this data into mysql table.

```
  fdsfsfrerwrwrwr_Core             55000:10011608      ipv4        Vl1162
  xcvbdtykgjfhffghrfhfhffghCore    55000:10014478      ipv4        Vl1447
  675436346ore                     55000:1004868       ipv4
  545_Core                         55000:1004128       ipv4
  345235345                        55000:2728          ipv4
  534534e                          55000:1002108       ipv4        Vl2105
  C8567566756Core                  55000:10021038      ipv4        Vl2103
  C546346453554_Core               55000:2105898       ipv4        Vl664
                                                                   Vl896
  ewttt_WAN_Core                   55000:1007967       ipv4        Vl2552
  tetrewCore                       55000:1001708       ipv4        Vl905
  gsdgdsfgore                      55000:100106        ipv4
  65434533_Core                    55000:1009418       ipv4        Vl941
                                                                   Vl1028
  I2222222-11                      55000:10008         ipv4
  I666r555-12                      55000:20002         ipv4        Vl749
                                                                   Vl874
                                                                   Vl894
                                                                   Vl942
                                                                   Vl1172
                                                                   Vl1439
                                                                   Vl2553
  345345353Core                    55000:1004068       ipv4        Vl50
  5345345Core                      55000:1004498       ipv4        Vl617
  S534534                          55000:1002798       ipv4        Vl779
  534535335Core                    55000:1004278       ipv4
  test                             55000:500500        ipv4
```

I want to use AWK or any other tool to produce result similar to following so that I can insert this data into mysql database. I have used following AWK command. cat sample.data | awk '{print $1","$2","$3","$4}'

```
TEST1_Core,990010:10011608,ipv4,Vl1162
AA2_Autism_Core,990010:10014478,ipv4,Vl1447
6753312_Core,990010:1004868,ipv4,
542343423,990010:1004128,ipv4,
Bgdfdfgdf,990010:2728,ipv4,
gfgCore,990010:1002108,ipv4,Vl2105
fgdfgfgdfg_Core,990010:10021038,ipv4,Vl2103
42342342342342Core,990010:2105898,ipv4,Vl664
```

Notice the last column has multiple rows associated to a single record.

```
  ghfghfhdfCore                    990010:1009418       ipv4        Vl941
                                                                   Vl1028
  hfghfghdf11                      990010:10008         ipv4
  yreyryer-12                      990010:20002         ipv4        Vl749
                                                                   Vl874
                                                                   Vl894
                                                                   Vl942
                                                                   Vl1172
                                                                   Vl1439
                                                                   Vl2553
```

How do I convert last column multiple rows so that I can following result.

```
ghfghfhdfCore,990010:1009418,ipv4,Vl941 Vl1028
hfghfghdf11,990010:10008,ipv4,
yreyryer-12,990010:20002,ipv4,Vl749 Vl874 Vl894 Vl942 Vl1172 Vl1439 Vl2553
```

I am sure someone must be able to help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
awk '
    BEGIN{OFMT="INSERT INTO `table` \
    VALUES(\n\t`%s`,\n\t`%s`,\n\t`%s`,\n\t`%s`\n);\n"
    }
    NF==3{printf OFMT, $1, $2, $3, $4v}
    NF==4{if (length(v)){printf OFMT, $1, $2, $3, $4v;v=""}
        else{printf OFMT, $1, $2, $3, $4}
    }
    NF==1{v=v","$1}
' file | mysql
```

### Output without [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql)

```
    INSERT INTO `table`     VALUES(
        `TEST1_Core`,
        `990010:10011608`,
        `ipv4`,
        `Vl1162`
);
INSERT INTO `table`     VALUES(
        `AA2_Autism_Core`,
        `990010:10014478`,
        `ipv4`,
        `Vl1447`
);
INSERT INTO `table`     VALUES(
        `6753312_Core`,
        `990010:1004868`,
        `ipv4`,
        ``
);
INSERT INTO `table`     VALUES(
        `542343423`,
        `990010:1004128`,
        `ipv4`,
        ``
);
INSERT INTO `table`     VALUES(
        `Bgdfdfgdf`,
        `990010:2728`,
        `ipv4`,
        ``
);
INSERT INTO `table`     VALUES(
        `gfgCore`,
        `990010:1002108`,
        `ipv4`,
        `Vl2105`
);
INSERT INTO `table`     VALUES(
        `fgdfgfgdfg_Core`,
        `990010:10021038`,
        `ipv4`,
        `Vl2103`
);
INSERT INTO `table`     VALUES(
        `42342342342342Core`,
        `990010:2105898`,
        `ipv4`,
        `Vl664`
);
INSERT INTO `table`     VALUES(
        `24234234N_Core`,
        `990010:1007967`,
        `ipv4`,
        `Vl2552,Vl896`
);
INSERT INTO `table`     VALUES(
        `C86765Core`,
        `990010:1001708`,
        `ipv4`,
        `Vl905`
);
INSERT INTO `table`     VALUES(
        `Dhyhyh_Core`,
        `990010:100106`,
        `ipv4`,
        ``
);
INSERT INTO `table`     VALUES(
        `ghfghfhdfCore`,
        `990010:1009418`,
        `ipv4`,
        `Vl941`
);
INSERT INTO `table`     VALUES(
        `hfghfghdf11`,
        `990010:10008`,
        `ipv4`,
        `,Vl1028`
);
INSERT INTO `table`     VALUES(
        `yreyryer-12`,
        `990010:20002`,
        `ipv4`,
        `Vl749,Vl1028`
);
INSERT INTO `table`     VALUES(
        `42342342_Core`,
        `990010:1004068`,
        `ipv4`,
        `Vl50,Vl874,Vl894,Vl942,Vl1172,Vl1439,Vl2553`
);
INSERT INTO `table`     VALUES(
        `gdfgdg_Core`,
        `990010:1004498`,
        `ipv4`,
        `Vl617`
);
INSERT INTO `table`     VALUES(
        `Spgdfggdf`,
        `990010:1002798`,
        `ipv4`,
        `Vl779`
);
INSERT INTO `table`     VALUES(
        `gdgdgdgdgCore`,
        `990010:1004278`,
        `ipv4`,
        ``
);
INSERT INTO `table`     VALUES(
        `test`,
        `990010:500500`,
        `ipv4`,
        ``
);
```

Comment: That will skip the lines that only have 3 fields and will not print the last record if it ends in a single-field line. Also, try it on the 3-record sample input at the end of the posted question. I did and it produced very odd output, maybe related to ignoring the 3-field line?

Comment: I still get very odd output for that 3-record input file, including the "Vli028" from the second line not becoming part of the first record as it should, but instead becoming part of both the second and 3rd records and most of the other single-field lines being skipped.

Comment: This is the closet match, but still unable to do what I want to do.

Comment: I am getting following output which is not in desired format, skipping lots of VLANs and has extra "`" mark.

Comment: @user2107349 as far as I can see the output my script produces is exactly what you asked for, would you mind clarifying where it's going wrong?

Comment: As you can see this field has has 7 rows with word V      I666r555-12                      55000:20002         ipv4        Vl749
Vl874
Vl894
Vl942
Vl1172
Vl1439
Vl2553  But this one is completed skipped, please check my original question I have just modified it with correct data. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Just don't print the end-of-line newline until you see how many fields the subsequent line has:

```
awk -v OFS="," '{$1=$1;printf "%s%s",(NF>1?n:" "),$0;n=ORS}END{print ""}' file
```

e.g.:

```
$ cat file
  ghfghfhdfCore                    990010:1009418       ipv4        Vl941
                                                                   Vl1028
  hfghfghdf11                      990010:10008         ipv4
  yreyryer-12                      990010:20002         ipv4        Vl749
                                                                   Vl874
                                                                   Vl894
                                                                   Vl942
                                                                   Vl1172
                                                                   Vl1439
                                                                   Vl2553

$ awk -v OFS="," '{$1=$1;printf "%s%s",(NF>1?n:" "),$0;n=ORS}END{print ""}' file
ghfghfhdfCore,990010:1009418,ipv4,Vl941 Vl1028
hfghfghdf11,990010:10008,ipv4
yreyryer-12,990010:20002,ipv4,Vl749 Vl874 Vl894 Vl942 Vl1172 Vl1439 Vl2553
```

I just noticed you can have some lines with only 3 fields and need to add a comma at the end in that case:

```
$ awk -v OFS="," 'NF==3{sub(/$/,OFS)} {$1=$1;printf "%s%s",(NF>1?n:" "),$0;n=ORS} END{print ""}' file
ghfghfhdfCore,990010:1009418,ipv4,Vl941 Vl1028
hfghfghdf11,990010:10008,ipv4,
yreyryer-12,990010:20002,ipv4,Vl749 Vl874 Vl894 Vl942 Vl1172 Vl1439 Vl2553
```

If your fields are actually tab-separated or there's spaces after the 3rd field there is another solution.

Comment: Well, actually my fields are tab separated, what is the solution for that please ?

Comment: Actually, that solutions fine for tab-separated too.

Comment: @user2107349 as far as I can see the output my script produces is exactly what you asked for but you say another solution is producing the output closest to your desired output, would you mind clarifying where my script is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to follow the common rule “use programs that do only one task, but do it well.” So, let’s start with making your data consistent:

```
sed -ne '1h;1!H;${;g;s/\n\s\+\(\S\+\)/,\1/g;p;}'
```

This is a well-known one-liner for turning `sed` multiline.

Now it’s only your fantasy which may prevent you of operating your data in all the ways.

Comment: When I run that on the posted sample input (the smaller set towards the bottom) I get garbage output: `$ sed -ne '1h;1!H;${;g;s/\n\s\+\(\S\+\)/,\1/g;p;}' file
  ghfghfhdfCore                    990010:1009418       ipv4        Vl941,Vl1028,hfghfghdf11
              990010:10008         ipv4,yreyryer-12                      990010:20002         ipv4
      Vl749,Vl874,Vl894,Vl942,Vl1172,Vl1439,Vl2553`.

Comment: Your latter example has leading spaces in every line. Is this necessary? If yes, try `sed 's/^\s*//g' file | sed -ne '1h;1!H;${;g;s/\n\s\+\(\S\+\)/,\1/g;p;}'`.

Comment: Oh, my fault, sorry. The pipe will not work here. `sed 's/^\s*//g' file > file1 && sed -ne '1h;1!H;${;g;s/\n\s\+\(\S\+\)/,\1/g;p;}' file1` finally should do the trick.

Comment: :-). sed is an excellent tool for simple substitution on a single line. For anything else, just use awk as the solution will be much simpler, clearer, easy to enhance. etc. etc. and usually briefer too. If you find yourself using more than s, g and p (with -n) in sed then you're using the wrong tool.

Comment: @EdMorton you are definitely saving with `C-x C-s`, not with `:w`, aren’t you? ;-) Actually since a task is to _fix markup_, `sed` is the right choice. Once a markup is fixed, I would use `awk`, or even `cut`.

Comment: @mudasobwa - I'm sorry I have no idea what any of that comment means.

Comment: This solution does not work for me at all, does not do anything apart from deleting the leading blank spaces

Answer (score 0):

Other awk approach, a bit more 'The awky way':

```
'NF>1{print line;line=$1 "," $2 "," $3 "," $4} NF==1{line=line " " $1}'
```

Comment: that wouldn't print the last record in the file and it would put a superfluous blank space before the first of the field3 values on each output row.

Comment: Correct. Need to add END {print line}

Comment: That would still leave a leading blank line and blanks at the start of field3s.

Comment: Yes,yes, but I don't think the answers should spoon-feed anyone. The point is to show the path, not doing the work for others.